# No matches converting function in C++ error

Tags: c++

When I run the code snippet I get the following error.

error: no matches converting function ‘exp’ to type ‘struct std::complex (*)(struct std::complex)’. However when I call exp() inside main() passing a complex argument to it,it runs fine. Can somebody please help?

```
using namespace std;

complex<long double> testExp(complex<double>(*test_func)(complex<double>), complex<double> x) {

        complex<double> result = test_func(x);
        return result;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    constexpr complex<double> x = (5.0, 15.0);

    complex<double> result =  testExp(exp<complex<double>>, x);

    complex<double> result1 = exp(x); /*This compiles fine */

    cout<< result << " " << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `exp<double>` ?

Comment: @songyuanyao  Works fine for exp<double>. I need to write a function that accepts a complex function as an input argument and invokes it.

Comment: For [`std::exp(std::complex)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp), when template parameter `T` is specified as `double`, the function parameter type would be `const complex<double>&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp), the prototype is `complex<T> exp( const complex<T>& z )`.

You should declare your function pointer as `complex<double>(*test_func)(const complex<double>&)`.

Then, at the call site, use `exp<double>`.

The result of the function is `complex<long double>` but `result` is `complex<double>`, you should change its type to `complex<long double>` (or change the result of the function).